# Dapper querysingle causes an EndOfStreamException

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper

For a very specific query I get an end of stream exception.

It always happens for the same query -  and this query can easily be executed as an SQL query but

but using dapper and its connection query it somehow seem to fail

I get `EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.`

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.Ensure.__EnsureLong|0()
```

I am not sure why i get this exception and where it goes wrong - this only returns and error for one specific query with a specific set of parameters.

I am not sure I understand whether this error is caused by the actual SQL query, or the by the parameters being parsed to it since my querySingle is executed as

```
    IDictionary<string, object> insertedEntityRegistration = connection.QuerySingle(insertNewRegistrationSql, parameters);
```

Full stacktrace:

```
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<<Ensure>g__EnsureLong|0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<<DoReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<NextResult>d__44.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__102.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteReaderWithFlagsFallback(IDbCommand cmd, Boolean wasClosed, CommandBehavior behavior) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 1051
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryRowImpl[T](IDbConnection cnn, Row row, CommandDefinition& command, Type effectiveType) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 1177
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.QuerySingle[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 781
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.QuerySingle(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 687
```

I am completly lost on what goes wrong here - since the query can without dapper be executed without any problem I dont understand why it causes this when executed with dapper.

all the parameters are there - they all have values, are being mapped to right one.

Is there somehow possible to debug the query it generates? 
What can cause this issue?

The query itself is something similar to

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
                    VALUES (1, tsrange('0001-01-01T00:00:01', '9999-01-01T00:00:02'), 'Application', tsrange('0001-01-01T00:00:01', '9999-01-01T00:00:02'),
                'name','mail',4511,4511)
                    RETURNING a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
```

Comment: in `insertedEntityRegistration` are you making an `INSERT` ? Can you post an example of the query that you are passing to the `connection.QuerySingle()` method?

Comment: Seeing the SQL statement would certainly help a lot.

Comment: i added the generated SQL statement -  it does not seem to fail at executing it, as I can execute without any problems.

Comment: @Anouar I added an SQL example

Answer (score 0):

For `INSERT` statements you need to use [Dapper Execute](https://dapper-tutorial.net/execute) and not `QuerySingle()`.

For example in your case:

```
var insertSqlStatement = "your INSERT query here";
var affectedRows = connection.Execute(insertSqlStatement,  new {ParameterName = "ParemeterValue"});
```

Comment: which ones? You use `QuerySingle()` for other `INSERT` statements?

Comment: yes .. But I also need to the output on to this object  `IDictionary<string, object>`